# Было ли такое правило? Деепричастие

Tags: деепричастный-оборот, пунктуация, сложности

*Хаджи-Мурат остановился бросив поводья и привычным движением правой руки.* Преподаватель выделил запятыми "бросив поводья". Разве не было такого правила, что если деепричастие идёт после глагола, то запятые не нужны. Есть такое? *Остановился бросив.*

Answer (score 4):

**Правило есть, но не такое.**

Позиция после глагола **способствует обособлению, но не является причиной**. Обособляться или не обособляться деепричастие может в разных позициях. Основная форма ― это обособление; отсутствие обособления говорит о том, что деепричастие не обозначает второе действие, а выступает в функции наречия (а наречие  обычно располагается после глагола).

[Знаки препинания при обособленных обстоятельствах | Справочник Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121)

§ 70. Одиночные деепричастия обособляются при сохранении ими глагольного значения — обозначении действия.

§ 71. Деепричастия и деепричастные обороты не обособляются:

1) если деепричастие непосредственно примыкает к глаголу и имеет значение образа действия: *Не спеша бегут лошади среди зеленых холмистых полей* (Бун.) Такие деепричастия по функции сближаются с наречием.

**Примеры с обособлением деепричастия в разных позициях** (обозначение второго действия):

**Задумавшись**, князь шёл по тропинке. **Играя**, в небе промелькнёт рассыпанная стая скворцов. **Оглянувшись**, Илья с весёлой улыбкой вскочил.

К ней, **лая**, кинулись собаки. Татьяна, **вспыхнув**, задрожала.

Григорий молчал, **задумавшись**. Верблюдов длинный ряд дорогой тянется, **мелькая.**